# Transform/move elements from std::list to std::vector

Tags: c++, list, vector

I need to convert `std::list< customStruct >` to `std::vector<std::string>`.
Is it possible to **move** all data from the `customStruct::s_` into the vector of stings?

```
customStruct
{
    std::string s_;
};
```

Is it work for `std::transform` and `std::make_move_iterator`?
Is this example correct? Will it really move strings?

```
std::list< customStruct > list;
std::vector< std::string> vt;

vt.reserve( list.size() );

std::transform( std::make_move_iterator( list.begin() ), std::make_move_iterator( list.end() ),
vt.begin(), [](const auto& el ) -> std::string
    {
        return std::move( el.s_ );
    } );
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your lambda takes `[](const auto& el )` by const reference, the `el` is declared as `const customStruct&`, so `el.s_` will be a `const std::string` (and the function will copy). You can instead take `customStruct&&` (or by universal reference `auto&&`). You can also not use move iterators and instead have your lambda take non-const lvalue references.

You also can't transform into `vt.begin()` because this will write to uninitailized elements (their memory only reserved, they are not actually constructed). Use [`std::back_inserter(vt)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) instead.

One example:

```cpp
std::list< customStruct > list = /* something */;

std::vector<std::string> vt;
vt.reserve(list.size());
std::transform(list.begin(), list.end(), std::back_inserter(vt), [](auto& el) -> std::string&& {
    return std::move(el.s_);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `resize` the vector before transforming into it. `reserve` only allocates capacity and then `transform` assigns to non-existing vector elements. Thats undefined behavior. Alternatively stay with `reserve` and use a `back_inserter`.

To see if it actually moves the elements you can add some output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


struct moveable {
    moveable() {}
    moveable(moveable&&){ std::cout << "move ctr\n"; }
    moveable& operator=(const moveable&){ return *this;}
    moveable(const moveable&) { std::cout << "copy ctr\n"; }
};

struct customStruct
{
    moveable m;
    std::string s_;
};
int main() {
std::list< customStruct > list;
list.push_back({});
list.push_back({});
list.push_back({});

std::vector< moveable > vt;

vt.resize( list.size() );

std::cout << "transform:\n";

std::transform( std::make_move_iterator( list.begin() ), std::make_move_iterator( list.end() ),
vt.begin(), [](const auto& el ) -> moveable
    {
        return std::move( el.m );
    } );

std::cout << "transform2\n";
std::transform( std::make_move_iterator( list.begin() ), std::make_move_iterator( list.end() ),
vt.begin(), [](auto&& el ) -> moveable
    {
        return std::move( el.m );
    } );

}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/Paaof8d65):

```
move ctr
move ctr
move ctr
transform:
copy ctr
copy ctr
copy ctr
transform2
move ctr
move ctr
move ctr
```

You cannot move from a `const&` thats why your code is not moving.